# I'm using two for loops and wants 25 "i"(inner loop) values w.r.t the "j" or X[] values.but it shows something different.plz help me

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm using two for loops and wants 25 "i"(inner loop) values w.r.t the "j" or X[] values.but it shows something different.plz help me.
this is my code

```
  int X[] = {1,2,3,5,10,20,30,40};
  for(int j=0;j<X.length;j++)
  {
    System.out.println("J: "+j+":"+X[j]);
    for (i=0; i < 25; i++)
    {
      K1[i] = (float) (((C1[i] * (Math.pow(X[j], A1[i]))) + (D1[i] * tanh(X[i]/(Xk1[i] - 2))) - tanh(-2)) / (1 - tanh(-2)));`

      System.out.println("k1: "+i+":"+K1[i]);

      K2[i] = (float) (((C2[i] * (Math.pow(X[j], A2[i]))) + (D2[i] * tanh(X[i]/(Xk2[i] - 2))) - tanh(-2)) / (1 - tanh(-2)));

      System.out.println("k2: "+i+":"+K2[i]);
    }
  }
```

and output

```
J: 0:1
k1: 0:0.77030677
k2: 0:0.71177393
k1: 1:0.85542655
k2: 1:0.7439147
k1: 2:1.0791008
k2: 2:1.4420886
k1: 3:1.4016204
k2: 3:0.99215466
k1: 4:1.6363927
k2: 4:1.1519849
k1: 5:1.8587888
k2: 5:1.2869722
k1: 6:2.1131036
k2: 6:1.4581378
k1: 7:2.2821712
k2: 7:1.5228558
```

Comment: Why are you checking your values < 25?

Comment: Does your this code really compiles and shows output?

Comment: You should state clearly what the desired output is. It also helps us to help you if you explain what your code actually does (or trying to do).

Comment: #adya...because each array containing 25 float values, except X[]. and i want to print k1 and k2 25 times w.r.t X[]. for example,for j=1, k1 and k2 execute 25 times. again for j=2, k1 and k2 execute 25 times and so on upto X.length=8

Comment: plz guide me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the array X has less than 25 items, you are going to get exception after 8th iteration of inner loop. It seems like you should not use i variable to index X array. see this part:

```
tanh(X[i]/(Xk1[i] - 2)))
```

Comment: thankqu so much sir.......but it was my small mistake. actually i have done X[i] instead of X[j].thats why problem was occuring.